# Two divs filling up available space

Tags: html, css

I want to put two divs next to each other in one block of fixed width. The right div is variable length (unknown one line text). The left div contains an image background (nice dash) and must fill up the remaining space.

Here is illustration of the problem:

```
|<---         400px           --->|
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
| ----------------- Variable text |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">some text</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**: right div MUST have transparent background!

Thanks

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? Any chance it's only browsers that [support Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)? Or do you need standard boring support for browsers like IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/bSMen/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="right">some text</div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

Yes, unfortunately `#left` and `#right` had to be swapped.

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px dashed #666
}
#left, #right {
    height: 100px
}
#left {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #f0f
}
#right {
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #0ff
}
```

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiice! Thanks a lot. Very simple and elegant solution :))

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way would be:

```
<div style="width:500px">
    <div style="DASH BG"><div style="BG TO HIDE DASH">Text</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I do NOT want to hide dash background (webpage design contains many gradients and it would pane to cut and maintain background parts).

Answer (score 0):

I would use float:

```
<div style="width:400px;">
   <div style="float:left;background-image:url('bgdesert.jpg');"></div>
   <div style="float:right;">Your text here</div>
   <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: In your example left div would be 0px width. There must be no gap between two divs.

Comment: You are still wrong. I changed background to outline. see whats happening: http://jsfiddle.net/3rQsB/1/

Comment: @Atheist: The only problem with your second answer (the one in your comment) is that you have `overfloat:hidden` instead of `overflow:hidden`. Besides that, it's "the same" solution I've given. I didn't see your comment beforehand. (not that it matters, I've posted the same solution before quite a few times)

Comment: @thirtyDot: You are right. I haven't used overflow:  that much lately... (Besides, working in c# for the last week hasn't helped either.)